# How to suppress split views in an iOS 8 master detail app

Tags: view, split, uisplitviewcontroller

Using iOS 8 and Xcode 6, I have created an universal Master/Detail app using the template.

When run on an iPad, it tries to display both master and detail views side by side.  In this app having them both on the screen is a big nuisance.  How do I get the iPad to open to the master view and segue to the detail view just as if it was an iPhone?

Further motivation for this: there is a collection view in the detail view and it misbehaves when the split view controller tries to load it.

Any insights you offer are much appreciated.